# How to pass variables in a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm practicing lambda expressions right now, this program I made is getting the weighted average of a subject, the first lambda expression **'get_avg'** is getting the data while the process is the **'sum_avg'**, when it runs the sum_avg is outputting **'-nan(ind)'** and it is not the answer I wanted.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
int main() {
float m = 0, w = 0;
auto get_avg = [](float m, float w) {

    cout << "ENTER THE GRADE: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "ENTER THE UNITS: ";
    cin >> w;
    return m, w;
};
get_avg(m, w);
auto sum_avg = [](float m,float w){
    cout << "THE WEIGHTED AVERAGE IS :" <<m*w/w << endl;
};
sum_avg(m,w);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, in C++ you cannot return multiple values from function. Line `return m, w;` behaves as `return w`, since `m, w` expression uses comma operator, which simply returns its right operand. (For reference, in newer standards you can use structured bindings thing, but I don't recommend it for now)

Comment: There's a bit of a philosophical conundrum to this example. You've got an unnamed function (lambda) which you name `get_avg`. Why not use an ordinary (named) function then?

Comment: @MSalters `get_avg` only exists in the scope of `main` (not a great reason in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you to be able to change the values of `main`-function's `m` and `w`, you need to pass them into the `get_avg` lambda by reference:

```
// you didn't need <thread> header, don't include it
#include<iostream>

// Never ever take the whole std namespace into your program!
// Take only the names you need,
// or just use the fully qualified names, e.g. std::cout everywhere.
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    float m = 0, w = 0;
    auto get_avg = [](float &m, float &w) {
        cout << "ENTER THE GRADE: ";
        cin >> m;
        cout << "ENTER THE UNITS: ";
        cin >> w;
    };
    get_avg(m, w);
    auto sum_avg = [](float m,float w){
        cout << "THE WEIGHTED AVERAGE IS :" <<m*w/w << endl;
    };
    sum_avg(m,w);
    system("PAUSE");  // I'm not sure why you use this here.
    return 0;
}
```

You could alternatively take the variables by value, and return a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) from the first lambda. Then you could use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to assign its return value to `m`, and `w`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    float m = 0, w = 0;
    auto get_avg = [](float m, float w) {
        std::cout << "ENTER THE GRADE: ";
        std::cin >> m;
        std::cout << "ENTER THE UNITS: ";
        std::cin >> w;
        return std::make_pair(m, w);
    };
    std::tie(m, w) = get_avg(m, w);
    auto sum_avg = [](float m, float w){
        std::cout << "THE WEIGHTED AVERAGE IS :" << m*w/w << std::endl;
    };
    sum_avg(m, w);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way this `m*w/w` is not really doing much, I let you figure out why.

Comment: so in order to pass it i must use their pointer to tweak the data from that variable?

Comment: It's a [reference, not a pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-vs-references-cpp/). But yes, if you want to change the values of the variables, you need to pass them by reference, not by value.

Answer (score 2):

Your first lambda did not return what you are expecting.
You must first understand the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to realize that `return m, w;` does not work as you think.
In fact it returns `w`.

Second, you call `get_avg(m, w)` but don't care about the result.
`m` and `w` are parameters (local variables) of your lambda, hiding the `m` and `w` variables of the outer scope.

You may use [lambda capture](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) to solve your issue, or make your first lambda return a `std::pair<float, float>` and inject those into your second lambda:

```
int main() {
float m = 0, w = 0;
// [&]  means Capture any referenced variable by reference
auto get_avg = [&]() {
    cout << "ENTER THE GRADE: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "ENTER THE UNITS: ";
    cin >> w;
};
get_avg(m, w);
auto sum_avg = [&](){
    cout << "THE WEIGHTED AVERAGE IS :" <<m*w/w << endl;
};
sum_avg(m,w);
system("PAUSE");  // I'm not sure why you use this here.
return 0;
}
```

To clarify:

- `[]` Capture nothing (or, a scorched earth strategy?)
- `[&]` Capture any referenced variable by reference
- `[=]` Capture any referenced variable by making a copy
- `[=, &foo]` Capture any referenced variable by making a copy, but capture variable `foo` by reference
- `[bar]` Capture `bar` by making a copy; don't copy anything else
- `[this]` Capture the `this` pointer of the enclosing class

Capture may be tricky because it is dependent on the scope of the lambda definition. If you return a lambda, you capture (invalid) references to local variables that do not exist any more.

Comment: can i ask what other operators i can use inside the '[]'?

Comment: @JansenLloydMacabangun Thats too broad a question for a comment. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda covers lambdas in detail.